# What is the right way to put app on production - assets not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Like in topic - what is the right way to put application on production mode. Right now any of my img in assets doesnt load. I havent got any img, fonts and assets - also for fancybox-rails gem there is no assets. I try everything and only with config.assets.compile = true it works fine.

```
config.cache_classes = true


  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true


  config.serve_static_assets = true


  config.assets.compress = true


  config.assets.compile = false


  config.assets.digest = true
```

This doesnt work.

```
 config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"


... /assets/Lato-Bol.ttf 404 (Not Found)  \
.../assets/fancybox-40d79ef494fcf5ca4727cb13b9e69c33.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Did you run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```